# JavaFX: TreeTableView and expanding items without children

Tags: java, javafx

I have TreeTableView with items. I want that user see the "arrow" to expand even if item has no children. The reason is very simple - lazy load. When user clicks at arrow program checks if there are possible items (for example in DB). If children for this item exist then they are added to item. If they don't exist the "arrow" must disappear. How to do it?

Comment: You could maybe add dummy items with no actual content under empty items. Then, when the user clicks the arrow, remove the dummy item and replace it with loaded content from the database.

Comment: @RedRoboHood I also thought about it. But maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Doesn't the example in the [Javadocs for `TreeItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html) have this functionality?

Comment: @James_D It seems to be what I am looking for. I need time to test it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Javadocs for `TreeItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html) show an example that basically does this. You can override the `isLeaf` and `getChildren` methods to lazily instantiate the children. Here's the same idea adapted for a `TreeTableView`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LazyTreeTable extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeTableView<Item> treeTable = new TreeTableView<>();
        TreeTableColumn<Item, String> nameCol = new TreeTableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().nameProperty());
        nameCol.setPrefWidth(250);
        TreeTableColumn<Item, Number> valueCol = new TreeTableColumn<>("Value");
        valueCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().valueProperty());
        valueCol.setPrefWidth(150);
        treeTable.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(nameCol, valueCol));

        treeTable.setRoot(new ItemTreeNode(new Item(1)));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(treeTable), 400, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class ItemTreeNode extends TreeItem<Item> {
        private boolean childrenLoaded = false ;

        public ItemTreeNode(Item value) {
            super(value);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf() {
            if (childrenLoaded) {
                return getChildren().isEmpty() ;
            }
            return false ;
//          return getChildren().isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public ObservableList<TreeItem<Item>> getChildren() {
            if (childrenLoaded) {
                return super.getChildren();
            }

            childrenLoaded = true ;
            if (getValue().getValue() < 100_000) {
                List<TreeItem<Item>> children = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
                    children.add(new ItemTreeNode(new Item(getValue().getValue() * 10 + i)));
                }
                super.getChildren().addAll(children);
            } else {
                // great big hack:
                super.getChildren().add(null);
                super.getChildren().clear();
            }
            return super.getChildren() ;
        }
    }

    public static class Item {
        private IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        public Item(int value) {
            this(String.format("Item %,d", value), value);
        }

        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested the example for Javadocs. However it is not 100% what I am looking for. Look, when item is shown isLeaf method is executed. Here we return false (user didn't click - we don't know). When user clicks the logic is executed. Suppose - no children inside. Now we can return true for isLeaf method. However, this method is not calle until we close parent etc. How can we make javafx call isLeaf method, something like refresh etc?

Comment: That's going to be tricky. The problem is (imo) the API for the `leaf` property in `TreeItem` was written incorrectly; `leafProperty()` is `final` and `isLeaf()` is not: it should have been the other way around. The problem is that if you override `isLeaf` it's no longer consistent with `leafProperty`; and there's no way to change the value of `leafProperty` other than changing the value of the child list, or employing a great big hack (see update).

Comment: One other thing you might consider is to load the children "one level down". If you implement the `isLeaf()` method just as `return getChildren().isEmpty();`, (and remove the great big hack), then the children will be loaded as soon as node is displayed (instead of as soon as a node is expanded). This gives slightly less laziness, but enables "leaf checking" as soon as the node is displayed.

Comment: Why do you call it a great big hack? Is it often used for refreshing javafx nodes which are linked with observable lists?

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be. This is the only case I've come across where it's necessary; in all other cases I've seen it used it's basically a hack to fix an incorrectly implemented model class. The point is that in JavaFX the views are supposed to observe JavaFX observable properties, and if things are set up correctly, changing the value of a property is enough for the view to know to update. Here, we simply have no mechanism for updating (or overriding) the `leafProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who found this during a google search for how to get the arrow to show up on a TreeItem that has no children, this is what I learned.

All you have to do is Override the isLeaf() method of TreeItem and have it return false then the arrow will show up.

If you wanted a method that only returns empty TreeItems with the arrow enabled, you could do it like this (and I chose String for simplicity but using a custom class would be fine as well):

```
private TreeItem<String> emptyArrowItem(String itemsString) {
    return new TreeItem<>(itemsString) {
        @Override public boolean isLeaf() {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you wanted to use a custom class for TreeItem and then base whether or not it's an empty Item with the expand arrow showing using that class, you could do it like this:

```
private TreeItem<CustomTreeItem> createItem(final CustomTreeItem customTreeItem) {

    return new TreeItem<>(customTreeItem) {
        
        private boolean isLeaf;
        private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true;

     @Override public boolean isLeaf() {
            if (isFirstTimeLeaf) {
                isFirstTimeLeaf = false;
                CustomTreeItem cti = getValue();
                isLeaf = cti.isEmptyItem();
            }
             return isLeaf;
        }
    };
}
```

This example comes straight out of the example given in [the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html) for the TreeItem class, only I simplified it quite a bit which makes it a bit easier to understand.