# JavaFX Optimized Asynchronous Lazy Loading of TreeItems on TreeView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have an app where i have a **TreeView** which will have **TreeItems** holding a *large number* of leaf TreeItems. Having a huge number of TreeItems in the treeview hurts the performance of the app noticeably, to avoid that, what i will do, is i will allow only one non-leaf TreeItem to be expanded at a time, and once a TreeItem is folded, i will clear it's children, and load them **asynchronously** once needed (**When the user expands the TreeItem**).

The weird issue is, in this test below, when i first click the expand arrow on the treeitem, the children load fine, and if i fold it (which will clear children) and unfold it again, sometimes it works and others the `program hogs and starts consuming 30% of the cpu for a couple of minutes` then gets back running. **What's weirder** is that if i double click on the TreeItem to expand it (Not using the arrow) the hog starts right away, even at first program launch.

What could i be possibly doing wrong here?

**PS:**

- Some of the code in the LazyTreeItem class is inspired by **James_D's** answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185441/javafx-treetableview-and-expanding-items-without-children)
- I tried running the loadItems task on the fx thread(Not using the ItemLoader), but it didn't make any difference.
- Same issue occurs using both **JAVA 8** and **JAVA 9**

> **App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

    private TreeView<Item> treeView = new TreeView<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("TreeView Lazy Load");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(treeView), 300, 275));
        initTreeView();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void initTreeView() {
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);
        treeView.setRoot(new TreeItem<>(null));

        List<SingleItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            items.add(new SingleItem(String.valueOf(i)));
        }
        TreeItem<Item> parentItem = new TreeItem<>(new Item());
        parentItem.getChildren().add(new LazyTreeItem(new MultipleItem(items)));

        treeView.getRoot().getChildren().add(parentItem);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> **LazyTreeItem.java**

```
public class LazyTreeItem extends TreeItem<Item> {
    private boolean childrenLoaded = false;
    private boolean isLoadingItems = false;

    public LazyTreeItem(Item value) {
        super(value);
        // Unload data on folding to reduce memory
        expandedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!newValue) {
                flush();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<TreeItem<Item>> getChildren() {
        if (childrenLoaded || !isExpanded()) {
            return super.getChildren();
        }
        if (super.getChildren().size() == 0) {
            // Filler node (will translate into loading icon in the
            // TreeCell factory)
            super.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(null));
        }
        if (getValue() instanceof MultipleItem) {
            if (!isLoadingItems) {
                loadItems();
            }
        }
        return super.getChildren();
    }

    public void loadItems() {
        Task<List<TreeItem<Item>>> task = new Task<List<TreeItem<Item>>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<TreeItem<Item>> call() {
                isLoadingItems = true;
                List<SingleItem> downloadSet = ((MultipleItem) LazyTreeItem.this.getValue()).getEntries();
                List<TreeItem<Item>> treeNodes = new ArrayList<>();
                for (SingleItem download : downloadSet) {
                    treeNodes.add(new TreeItem<>(download));
                }
                return treeNodes;
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                super.getChildren().clear();
                super.getChildren().addAll(task.getValue());
                childrenLoaded = true;
                isLoadingItems = false;
            });
        });
        ItemLoader.getSingleton().load(task);
    }

    private void flush() {
        childrenLoaded = false;
        super.getChildren().clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        if (childrenLoaded) {
            return getChildren().isEmpty();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

> **ItemLoader.java**

```
public class ItemLoader implements Runnable {
    private static ItemLoader instance;
    private List<Task> queue = new ArrayList<>();
    private Task prevTask = null;

    private ItemLoader() {
        Thread runner = new Thread(this);
        runner.setName("ItemLoader thread");
        runner.setDaemon(true);
        runner.start();
    }

    public static ItemLoader getSingleton() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ItemLoader();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public <T> void load(Task task) {
        if (queue.size() < 1) {
            queue.add(task);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                Task task = queue.get(0);
                if (task != prevTask) {
                    prevTask = task;
                    task.run();
                    queue.remove(task);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Model (**Item.java**, **SingleItem.java**, **MultipleItem.java**)

```
public class Item {

}
/****************************************************************
 **********                  SingleItem              ************
 ****************************************************************/
public class SingleItem extends Item {
    private String id;

    public SingleItem(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
/****************************************************************
 **********                  MultipleItem            ************
 ****************************************************************/
public class MultipleItem extends Item {

    private List<SingleItem> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    public MultipleItem(List<SingleItem> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    public List<SingleItem> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }

    public void setEntries(List<SingleItem> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in fx 10 (when double clicking on the item) - not when expanding on the triangle. No idea what happens, but: the leaf/leafProperty is not synched (due to the api bug, as James noted), so some internals - which are dirty anyway - might get into further trouble. In your shoes I would go into a profiling round: find the bottleneck with a profiler and then go from there.

Comment: ookay .. seems to be related to selection: if the expanding item is not selected, all is fine - if it is selected it hangs ...

Comment: it's hanging in TreeViewFocusModel which is buggy in checking the row of each of the added items (vs. querying the row of the last added in a block as TreeViewSelectionModel does) - no idea how to hack around, implementing a custom FocusModel might be a (nasty .. all is very hidden and very hard to extend) the only way out

Comment: @kleopatra
Ah, you are absolutely right, only happens when the item is selected, i spent hours yesterday trying to figure out what was happening and i didn't catch that, Thank you, i will see if i can see my way to implementing a custom FocusModel, or using some dirty hack.

Comment: @kleopatra Ah, i thought it was going to be an easy workaround, thought the there's a selected property on TreeItem, that i can cache, deselect the item prior to loading children, then reselect it after. Turns out the selected property is on the TreeCell which can hold any treeitem at any given time, and changes frequently. Thought i'd add a new boolean property in TreeItem that is changed prior to loading and in the update method of Treecell add a listener that will do the selection logic, but the listener ended up duplicating, and being called multiple times, and hang still occurs.

Comment: definitely a bug (will file it soon), and definitely (modulo missing tests ;) can be hacked by a custom FocusModel that queries the newly added items only if focusedIndex > sourceRow (c&p the default - which is diiirty by tweaking internal state of both treeItem and treeView ... which in turn requires dirty reflective access) and then do better than default impl, no reason to query each added item for its row, doing so for the last of the added bunch should be just fine

Comment: @kleopatra If/when you file the bug you should include the `TreeTableViewFocusModel` because it does pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue, as pointed out by @kleopatra, is caused by adding a *large* amount of children when there are one or more items selected. One way to fix this is to try and implement your own `FocusModel`, as the default `FocusModel` seems to be the source of the problem. Another, and in my opinion easier, way to create a workaround is to clear the selection before adding the large group of children; afterwards, you can re-select the items that were previously selected.

The way I went about doing this is by firing `TreeModificationEvent`s with custom `EventType`s. Also, I decided not to override `isLeaf()` inside my lazy `TreeItem`. I find it easier to use a placeholder `TreeItem` for when the parent `TreeItem` is a lazy branch. Since there is a placeholder the parent will register as a branch automatically.

Here's an example that browses the default `FileSystem`. To test if the solution worked I created a 100,000 file directory and opened it; there was no hang for me. Hopefully that means this can be adapted to your code.

<sup>Note: This example does remove the children when the branch is collapsed, just like you are doing in your code.</sup>

---

**App.java**

```
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  private static String pathToString(Path p) {
    if (p == null) {
      return "null";
    } else if (p.getFileName() == null) {
      return p.toString();
    }
    return p.getFileName().toString();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TreeView<Path> tree = new TreeView<>(new TreeItem<>());
    tree.setShowRoot(false);
    tree.setCellFactory(LazyTreeCell.forTreeView("Loading...", App::pathToString));
    TreeViewUtils.installSelectionBugWorkaround(tree);

    for (Path fsRoot : FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories()) {
      tree.getRoot().getChildren().add(new LoadingTreeItem<>(fsRoot, new DirectoryLoader(fsRoot)));
    }

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tree, 800, 600));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

}
```

**DirectoryLoader.java**

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;

public class DirectoryLoader implements Callable<List<? extends TreeItem<Path>>> {

  private static final Comparator<Path> COMPARATOR = (left, right) -> {
    boolean leftIsDir = Files.isDirectory(left);
    if (leftIsDir ^ Files.isDirectory(right)) {
      return leftIsDir ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return left.compareTo(right);
  };

  private final Path directory;

  public DirectoryLoader(Path directory) {
    this.directory = directory;
  }

  @Override
  public List<? extends TreeItem<Path>> call() throws Exception {
    try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(directory)) {
      return stream.sorted(COMPARATOR)
          .map(this::toTreeItem)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
  }

  private TreeItem<Path> toTreeItem(Path path) {
    return Files.isDirectory(path)
           ? new LoadingTreeItem<>(path, new DirectoryLoader(path))
           : new TreeItem<>(path);
  }

}
```

**LoadingTreeItem.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionException;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;

public class LoadingTreeItem<T> extends TreeItem<T> {

  private static final EventType<?> PRE_ADD_LOADED_CHILDREN
      = new EventType<>(treeNotificationEvent(), "PRE_ADD_LOADED_CHILDREN");
  private static final EventType<?> POST_ADD_LOADED_CHILDREN
      = new EventType<>(treeNotificationEvent(), "POST_ADD_LOADED_CHILDREN");

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  static <T> EventType<TreeModificationEvent<T>> preAddLoadedChildrenEvent() {
    return (EventType<TreeModificationEvent<T>>) PRE_ADD_LOADED_CHILDREN;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  static <T> EventType<TreeModificationEvent<T>> postAddLoadedChildrenEvent() {
    return (EventType<TreeModificationEvent<T>>) POST_ADD_LOADED_CHILDREN;
  }

  private final Callable<List<? extends TreeItem<T>>> callable;
  private boolean needToLoadData = true;

  private CompletableFuture<?> future;

  public LoadingTreeItem(T value, Callable<List<? extends TreeItem<T>>> callable) {
    super(value);
    this.callable = callable;
    super.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>());
    addExpandedListener();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private void addExpandedListener() {
    expandedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      if (!newValue) {
        needToLoadData = true;
        if (future != null) {
          future.cancel(true);
        }
        super.getChildren().setAll(new TreeItem<>());
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public ObservableList<TreeItem<T>> getChildren() {
    if (needToLoadData) {
      needToLoadData = false;
      future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new CallableToSupplierAdapter<>(callable))
          .whenCompleteAsync(this::handleAsyncLoadComplete, Platform::runLater);
    }
    return super.getChildren();
  }

  private void handleAsyncLoadComplete(List<? extends TreeItem<T>> result, Throwable th) {
    if (th != null) {
      Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler()
          .uncaughtException(Thread.currentThread(), th);
    } else {
      Event.fireEvent(this, new TreeModificationEvent<>(preAddLoadedChildrenEvent(), this));
      super.getChildren().setAll(result);
      Event.fireEvent(this, new TreeModificationEvent<>(postAddLoadedChildrenEvent(), this));
    }
    future = null;
  }

  private static class CallableToSupplierAdapter<T> implements Supplier<T> {

    private final Callable<T> callable;

    private CallableToSupplierAdapter(Callable<T> callable) {
      this.callable = callable;
    }

    @Override
    public T get() {
      try {
        return callable.call();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new CompletionException(ex);
      }
    }

  }

}
```

**LazyTreeCell.java**

```
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class LazyTreeCell<T> extends TreeCell<T> {

  public static <T> Callback<TreeView<T>, TreeCell<T>> forTreeView(String placeholderText,
                                                                   Callback<? super T, String> toStringCallback) {
    return tree -> new LazyTreeCell<>(placeholderText, toStringCallback);
  }

  private final String placeholderText;
  private final Callback<? super T, String> toStringCallback;

  public LazyTreeCell(String placeholderText, Callback<? super T, String> toStringCallback) {
    this.placeholderText = placeholderText;
    this.toStringCallback = toStringCallback;
  }

  /*
   * Assumes that if "item" is null **and** the parent TreeItem is an instance of
   * LoadingTreeItem that this is a "placeholder" cell.
   */
  @Override
  protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty) {
      setText(null);
      setGraphic(null);
    } else if (item == null && getTreeItem().getParent() instanceof LoadingTreeItem) {
      setText(placeholderText);
    } else {
      setText(toStringCallback.call(item));
    }
  }

}
```

**TreeViewUtils.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem.TreeModificationEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;

public class TreeViewUtils {

  public static <T> void installSelectionBugWorkaround(TreeView<T> tree) {
    List<TreeItem<T>> selected = new ArrayList<>(0);
    EventHandler<TreeModificationEvent<T>> preAdd = event -> {
      event.consume();
      selected.addAll(tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
      tree.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    };
    EventHandler<TreeModificationEvent<T>> postAdd = event -> {
      event.consume();
      selected.forEach(tree.getSelectionModel()::select);
      selected.clear();
    };
    ChangeListener<TreeItem<T>> rootListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      if (oldValue != null) {
        oldValue.removeEventHandler(LoadingTreeItem.preAddLoadedChildrenEvent(), preAdd);
        oldValue.removeEventHandler(LoadingTreeItem.postAddLoadedChildrenEvent(), postAdd);
      }
      if (newValue != null) {
        newValue.addEventHandler(LoadingTreeItem.preAddLoadedChildrenEvent(), preAdd);
        newValue.addEventHandler(LoadingTreeItem.postAddLoadedChildrenEvent(), postAdd);
      }
    };
    rootListener.changed(tree.rootProperty(), null, tree.getRoot());
    tree.rootProperty().addListener(rootListener);
  }

  private TreeViewUtils() {}
}
```

---

As implemented, the utility method that installs the workaround is tied to you using `LoadingTreeItem`s in the `TreeView`. I couldn't think of a good way to make the solution general enough to apply to any arbitrary `TreeView`; for that, I believe creating a custom `FocusModel` would be necessary.

There is probably a better way to implement the `LazyTreeCell` by using a class to wrap the real data—like what you're doing with `Item`. Then you could have an actual placehoder `Item` instance that tells the `TreeCell` that it is a placeholder rather than relying on what type the parent `TreeItem` is. As it is, my implementation is likely brittle.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this answer slaw. Sorry, i forgot to mention that the hang only happens when there's a huge amount of treeitems to be loaded, in my case 20,000 and above. I removed the isLeaf method as a whole but it didn't solve it. Does your solution work when a directory has 100,000 files?

Comment: I will try and do the test now.

Comment: I added this inside the else statement in directory loader `int count = 0;
                    while (++count < 100000) {
                        list.add(TreeData.createLeaf(fo));
                    }`, and expanded a drive with only one leaf file and the same hang occurred, @Kleopatra in the replies above found out it had to do with the item being selected/focused, in your example app the first treecell is always focused as indicated by the blue border, and therefore produces the hang immediately once treeitem is expanded.

Comment: arrgghh ... adding the cell into the mix is .. evil ... anyway, the issue is not related to lazy loading, happens whenever many children are added

Comment: @kleopatra And I realize the issue is adding a large amount of children. But, as you pointed out, it is only an issue when an item is selected. So instead of trying to implement a custom `FocusModel` I decided to try and clear the selection before adding the large group of children—the hanging issue disappears for me when loading a 100,000 file directory.

Comment: why do you burden the cell (vs. f.i. some listener in application/support code) with un/re-selecting? It's way too "small" for any "bigger" hacking logic ..

Comment: @kleopatra I put the logic in the `TreeCell` because it was the only place that occurred to me where I could "reach" the `TreeView` "through" a `TreeItem`. I suppose I could fire custom events and then add event handlers to the `TreeView`. Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: nothing special - just wanted to repeat (again, and again, and again :) that the cell is the wrong place to do such hacking. It's a really little piece in the overall puzzle and must not do stuff outside its scope ... normally <g> So if you can think of a better place, go ahead (your example is getting more complex by the minute, and I'm too lazy to really look into it .. my personal preference always is to simplify then apply - but that's just personal :)) Good work, btw!

Comment: @DarkMental I reworked my answer/example to try and better address the problem. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @Slaw
Thank you!! This was it, no hang anymore!!
I have one question though, what are the benefits of using a future instead of a task that i pass to ItemLoader? and does the Future::cancel method stop the execution immediately without any checking? Seems feasible to me here if that's the case.

Comment: @DarkMental No real advantage. Using a `Task` could be considered the "more JavaFX way". The reasons I used `CompletableFuture` are (1) it seemed simpler for a small example and (2) I'm not showing visual progress. And no, calling `cancel` doesn't stop the execution immediately. In fact, [`CompletableFuture.cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel(boolean)) behaves differently than a "normal" `Future`; it doesn't interrupt the `Thread`. Even if it did, my code doesn't check for interruption so it wouldn't stop execution anyway.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Again thank you and to @Kleopatra for taking the time to figure out the cause of the issue and the solution.

Comment: Wow, a lot of code. This answer really deserves more upvotes!

Comment: Thank you very much for this complete example.
Does anybody know why the installSelectionBugWorkaround method is used and which bug requires this workaround?

Comment: @Thorsten I don't know the exact bug ID, assuming kleopatra (or someone else) ever actually filed a bug report. But the problem, at least back in 2018, was that adding a large number of tree items to the tree view while an item was selected. Basically, in that case, it took forever for the items to be added due to bad code in the focus model implementation. The workaround caches what's selected, clears the selection, adds the items, and then reselects the appropriate items. It's possible this problem has been fixed since this answer was posted, and the workaround is no longer needed.

Comment: Note this Q&A is about the bug and a workaround, despite my answer providing working code for a lazily loaded tree view.